# An error of spelling/an error in spelling?

Tags: prepositions

I'm not sure if I have heard both phrases used, but something in my head tells me I have, and I am just wondering if they are both correct (I would appreciate it if you could provide an explanation). Another related question: is it possible to say "error of/in translation"? This question has been bothering me for quite a while. Thank you for your answers.

Answer (score 4):

Both "an error of ..." and "an error in spelling" are reasonable. I would use the second when talking about a particular example

> He made an error in spelling the word 'necessary' with two 'c's.

I would use the first when not referring to a specific example.

> His essay contained five errors of spelling.

But I'd be more likely to say:

> He made five spelling errors.

Answer (score -1):

> an error in spelling

or

> a spelling error

"an error of spelling," even though it may seem technically suitable, is nonsense.

Comment: Google Books claims to have 1500 written instances of [*an error **of** spelling*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22an+error+of+spelling%22), so I don't think I can let your "nonsense" assessment stand unchallenged. On top of which I can't see why ***orthography***, for example, should be any different to ***spelling*** in this context. And there are actually nearly twice as many instances of *an error **in** orthography* as there are of *an error **of** orthography.*

Comment: I agree with @Fumble – while it may sound the most awkward of the three options, and appear be [the least common](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=a+spelling+error%2Can+error+in+spelling%2Can+error+of+spelling&year_start=1935&year_end=1975&corpus=15&smoothing=6), it's a bit too dismissive to deem it as "nonsense."